# Is there a word that means the bad events?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word that simply means the bad events (that take place in a story). For example, I'm trying to use it in this way:

> Kino, as a male, has the role as being the scandalous character, causing the ____________ that take place.

I was thinking maybe the word "disaster" would fit, but I want a higher level word and a word that means the closest.

Comment: ".. **trouble** that takes place", because he's a troublemaker.

Comment: Why not **scandal**? He's a scandalous character anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An “obvious” term (that may be broader than you want) is [***plot***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plot).

> a series of events that form the story in a novel, movie, etc.

This might be used as

> Kino is the scandalous character who *drives the **plot.***

---

Another term that may be closer to what you want is ***conflict***.

> discord of action, feeling, or effect;
>   antagonism or opposition, as of interests or principles
>                            [— dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conflict)
>
> opposition between characters or forces in a work of drama or fiction,
>   especially when motivating or shaping the action of the plot.
>        [— The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conflict)
>   <sup>([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conflict) says almost the exact same thing.)</sup>
>
> the forces that oppose each other to create the plot in a story, book, or film
>                           [— the Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/conflict)

For example,

> Kino, as a male, has the role as being the scandalous character,
>   causing the ***conflict*** that is the basis for the story.
>   or
>                       …, causing the ***conflict*** that drives the plot.

Answer (score 0):

The word "**misadventure**" is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/misadventure) as

> an unfortunate incident; a mishap

Answer (score 0):

**Trouble** — [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trouble)

> *(mass noun)* 1. Difficulty or problems

*"Kino, as a male, has the role as being the scandalous character, causing the trouble that take place."*

Or maybe, "**scandal**", because he's already scandalous.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many words for what can go wrong. The reasons are obvious. One is:s
SNAFU (military: Situation Normal All F____ Up), blunder, screw up, failure, and so on. Each expression has its own application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sound dramatic, you can go with **[the] apocalypse**.

> Kino, as a male, has the role as being the scandalous character,
>   causing the apocalypse that [will] take place.

From [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/apocalypse):

> 1. The complete final destruction of the world, especially as described in the biblical book of Revelation.
> 2. An event involving destruction or damage on an awesome or catastrophic scale, e.g. *a stock market apocalypse* or *an era of ecological apocalypse*.

Answer (score 0):

**[omen:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/omen)** *n.* An event regarded as a portent of good or evil:

> *'Kino, as a male, has the role as being the scandalous character, causing the **ill omens** that take place.'*